# Gradient of a summation

Tags: derivatives, summation

How to calculate the gradient of the following summation in terms of $x_i$ ?

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(x_i-a)^2$$

is the following answer true?

$$2 \sum_{i=0}^n(x_i-a)$$

Thank you

Comment: the gradient is a vector, whose components are derivatives of your function in variable $x_i$. So the first component of your gradient is $2(x_1-a)$

Comment: The gradient is the vector of the partial derivatives; $\partial_{x_i} \sum_{i=0}^n(x_i-a)=2(x_i-a)$. Can you now give me the gradient?

Comment: Thank you both for the quick answer! So the gradient will be the vector $2 (x_1-a, x_2-a, ..., x_n-a) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gradient is the vector of the partial derivatives; $\partial_{x_i} \sum_{i=0}^n (x_i−a)^2=2(x_i−a)$. So the first component of your gradient is $2(x_1−a)$.